# Struts2 return in action cant find another class file

Tags: struts2

```
 public class Login extends ActionSupport {

     //connection made  

     PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from register1 where username=? and password=?");
     pstmt.setString(1, username);
     pstmt.setString(2, pwd);

     ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();    

     if (rs.next()) {
         String role = rs.getString(3);
         if (role == null || role.equals("user")) {    
             session.setAttribute("username", username);
             return "Cart"; //here i want to go for another .java file
         }   
     }
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="Login" class="mypack.Login">
<result name="Cart" type="dispatcher">
        <param name="location">mypack.CartSelect</param>//Another .java file which support Action Support 
        </result>
</action>
```

Class 3:

```
public class CartSelect extends ActionSupport implements ServletContextAware {

public String execute() throws Exception {
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What do you mean, "can't find a class file"? That implies a deploy or compilation issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is not a dispatcher but instead a redirect.

[Here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/redirect-action-result.html) is the reference for redirect action result type.